# Direct SQL query from Model in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to execute a SQL query directly from Model in CI 4

Controller:

```
$homemodel = new \App\Models\home_model();

$data['list'] = $homemodel->myquery();
```

Model:

```
 public function myquery(){

  $query = "SELECT id FROM tab_anagr WHERE var = 1";
        
  $query=$this->db->query($query);
      
  return $query->result_array();
                
 }
```

Does'nt work and I receive this error:

> Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Result::result_array()

I would like to receive the array for the view.

Comment: I would like to use "free" queries in my models.

Comment: "free" queries means??

Comment: I would like to use raw code "SELECT a1, a2 FROM tab1 WHERE x = a" ect ect

Comment: that's all in the docs [Generating Query Results - Result Arrays](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-arrays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `$query->getResultArray()` to get the result as an array, if you want it as object you can use $query->getResult()

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id IN ? AND status = ? AND author = ?";

$db->query($sql, [[3, 6], 'live', 'Rick']);`